# Scriptable disassembly in gdb

Tags: assembly, scripting, gdb

I am dumping register contents, instruction by instruction, with a `gdb` script (this is not an interactive debugging session, `layout asm` or TUI mode are out of the picture).

I would like to add to the register values the machine code corresponding to the current instruction. I already found a trick to overcome the fact that the `disassemble` command is designed to give you a lot of context around the current instruction and that I don't know how many bytes I should disassemble to get the full instruction. Whatever the instruction size, a range of 1 takes care of this for me:

```
(gdb) disassemble $pc,$pc+1
Dump of assembler code from 0x400efe to 0x400eff:
=> 0x0000000000400efe <main+0>: push   %r15
End of assembler dump.
```

I have to go a step further and add a flag to display what I really want (`41 57`):

```
(gdb) disassemble /r $pc,$pc+1
Dump of assembler code from 0x400efe to 0x400eff:
=> 0x0000000000400efe <main+0>: 41 57   push   %r15
End of assembler dump.
```

There is another way to display this information:

```
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x400efe <main>: push   %r15
(gdb) x/x $pc
0x400efe <main>:    0x56415741
```

But I couldn't find a format specifier that would let me extract specifically `41 57` (I can live with `5741`). As you can see, the instruction oriented one disassembles without displaying the machine code, while the hexdump has no idea of the instruction length.

Finally, I need this value to end up in a `printf`, meaning that based on the current outputs I get, some parsing would still be needed. I am not sure this is doable within a pure `gdb` script.

I'd rather avoid relying on the `gdb` `python` layer if possible.

Do you know of any way to achieve what I'd like to do?